# Use of count to detemine occurances and concatenate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out if there are two records for CR.DestinationDepot, then concatenate them like (eg.): KNI/KHN as opposed to how it is being concatenated now. Any ideas? Thank you.

[image]

```
 select CR.DestinationCountry,
 mm.MovementRef,
CR.DestinationDepot,
case when count(CR.DestinationDepot) >= 2 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [statement],
 Case when (CR.DestinationCountry <> 'GB') and count(CR.DestinationDepot) >= 2 then CR.DestinationDepot+'/'+CR.DestinationDepot else CR.DestinationDepot end as [DestinationDepot]
 FROM    dbo.MALExport AS ME
    INNER JOIN dbo.movConLink AS MCL ON ME.ConsignmentReference = MCL.ConsignmentReference
    INNER JOIN dbo.cgtRoute AS CR ON CR.RouteID = MCL.CMRRouteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.movMovement AS MM ON MM.MovementRef = ME.MovementReference
    group by cr.DestinationCountry, cr.DestinationDepot, mm.MovementRef
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code should be what you are looking for

```
select CR.DestinationCountry,
 mm.MovementRef,
CR.DestinationDepot,
case when count(CR.DestinationDepot) >= 2 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [statement],
 Case when (CR.DestinationCountry <> 'GB') and count(CR.DestinationDepot) >= 2 then CR.DestinationDepot+'/'+CR.DestinationDepot else CR.DestinationDepot end as [DestinationDepot]
,stuff((SELECT '/' + CR2.DestinationDepot' '  FROM  dbo.cgtRout cr2
    WHERE CR.DestinationCountry <> 'GB' and CR2.RouteID = MCL.CMRRouteID  order by CR2.RouteID desc FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [DestinationDepot2]
 FROM    dbo.MALExport AS ME
    INNER JOIN dbo.movConLink AS MCL ON ME.ConsignmentReference = MCL.ConsignmentReference
    INNER JOIN dbo.cgtRoute AS CR ON CR.RouteID = MCL.CMRRouteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.movMovement AS MM ON MM.MovementRef = ME.MovementReference
    group by cr.DestinationCountry, cr.DestinationDepot, mm.MovementRef
```

Comment: Hi @RJ_ unfortunately this code didn't solve the issue. Thank you anyway